# IntelliJ IDEA: Green check sign in margin

Tags: user-interface, ide, intellij-idea

I was coding in IntelliJ IDEA when I mistakenly pressed some random key and this green "check" sign appeared in my IDE:

[IntelliJ IDEA screen capture](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1266614/greenCheck.png)

Any idea what this green "check" sign is for? I can't recall which key I pressed to make this appear...

Comment: The check is not green btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bookmark](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/managing-bookmarks.html).